# Does light have mass as it is attracted through gravitational force?

Tags: gravity, visible-light, mass

I have heard that no one escape from the intense gravitational field of a black hole (obviously that's why it is black). And gravitational force is due to the mass having the body, no mass no gravity, as 
$$F=GMm/r^2$$
Putting $0$ in one of the two bodies' masses, gives no gravitational force. 
But light cannot escape from black hole due to its strong gravity, *does that mean that light has mass*? please correct me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Light does not have mass and Newton's theory of gravity doesn't work here. Any massive object, like the Sun, locally deforms the flat fabric of spacetime into a curved one. Light bends because it has to follow the geodesic (shortest distance between two points in a curved space) as Einstein taught us in his general theory of relativity.